# JavaScript new Google Sign In - get user data: id, profile image and nickname

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

Since it's not possible to use the old way to sign in users any more I tried the new way:

```
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: googleSignInClientId,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("gooDiv"),
        { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
    );
    // google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
}
```

`response` contains all kind of useless nonsense, I used to get the user ID, profile image and the nickname, how to get those with the new way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.credential field is the ID token as a base64 encoded JSON Web Token (JWT) string.

This JWT, and contains the claim set from the authencation server about the user who has signed in to your application.  Try and take it and put it in https://jwt.io/ and you will see the claims returend.

```
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
        var tokens = response.credential.split(".");
        var payload = JSON.parse(atob(tokens[1]));
        console.log(`user id ${payload.sub}`)
        console.log(`user name ${payload.name}`)
        console.log(`user picture ${payload.picture}`)
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "[REDACTED]",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
        );
        google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    }
```

The JWT is in three parts, header, payload and signature. they are joined by a .

My code splits the jwt by the .

```
var tokens = response.credential.split(".");
```

Then parses the payload

```
var payload = JSON.parse(atob(tokens[1]));
```

Resulting in

```
 console.log(`user id ${payload.sub}`)
 console.log(`user name ${payload.name}`)
 console.log(`user picture ${payload.picture}`)
```